# PHP Script unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting this error on the following line of my PHP Script which is responsible for executing the mysqli_query. I'm not sure why it is occuring there :

`syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ']'`

```
<?php
$response = array("error" => FALSE);


if (isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['offset']) != '') {

 $city= $_POST['city'];
 $offset = $_POST['offset];




 $conn=mysqli_connect("****.com", "***", "***","****");


$get_images= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_id, image, longitude, latitude, city, geo_name_id, description, score, Categories FROM images WHERE geo_name_id = '$city' LIMIT 10 OFFSET '$offset'");

 $myArray = array();
$returnArray = array();
while($row = $get_images->fetch_array())
{
 $myArray["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
 $myArray["image"] = $row["image"];
 $myArray["longitude"] = $row["longitude"];
 $myArray["latitude"] = $row["latitude"];
 $myArray["city"] = $row["city"];
 $myArray["geo_name_id"] = $row["geo_name_id"];
 $myArray["description"] = $row["description"];
 $myArray["score"] = $row["score"];
 $myArray["Categories"] = $row["Categories"];

 $returnArray[] = $myArray;
}
echo json_encode($returnArray);


  }   

  ?>
```

I don't really see where it can expect a `]` here...

Comment: Please provide code for the variables you are setting in this line.

Comment: The error occurs in other parts of your code, you'll need to include more of your code

Comment: Makee, please read this information on how to craft a good code example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . FYI, your problem is undoubtedly caused by a syntax  error higher up in your code.

Comment: I updated the code, relax..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed out the close quote at:

```
$city= $_POST['city'];
$offset = $_POST['offset];
```

It should be: `$offset = $_POST['offset'];` instead.